# Notification Intent Not starting Actiivty android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I am trying to start an Activity on a Notification Click but it never get started. Below is my code for sending Notification:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("Notification", type);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,notificationIntent, 0);
        Notification n = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(type)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, n);
```

I never get call to that activity on click of notification.

Comment: Have you declared this service class at AndroidManifest?

Comment: I am recieving notification via FCM, Notification appears in Notification Bar, but clicking on it never calls activity. Activity is registered and working in the app.

Comment: last parameter in `getAcitivy` is flag, i think it should not be 0

Comment: Docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)

Comment: I have tried putting all that flags but no success FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

Comment: May be you have some redirect on app start?

Comment: you should use NotificationCompat.Builder in place Notification.Builder and TaskStackBuilder also to do this.

Comment: PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Comment: My Launcher activity is other activity, I want MainActivity to open on notification click . Have Tried using NotificationCompat.Builder and even Aniruddh 's solution.But no success.

Comment: @Saira Nawaz Try to add this : android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK inside Pending Intent 4th parameter instead of 0.

Comment: Post your manifest please

Comment: @AndyDeveloper You suggestion is wrong. 4th parameter is for `PendingIntent` flags, not for `Intent` flags.

Comment: @DavidWasser sorry bro but it works for me.Even many of my app in google market all are working with these code no issue.It works for me from 4.0 upto 6.0 version.Still not tested in 7.0. Anyways thanks for your comment. :)

Comment: @AndyDeveloper You are missing the point. Passing `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` in a call to `PendingIntent.getActivity()` is useless. It does nothing. You can remove that flag and the behaviour will be exactly the same. It is confusing and misleading to claim that this will change anything.

Answer (score 1):

> try this one
>   **Replace `Splash_Activity.class` with you activity and make sure you have register this class in `Manifest.xml`**

```
 protected void displayNotification(Context context, String[] strContent) {
            try {
                int numMessages = 0;

                /* Invoking the default notification service */
                NotificationCompat.Builder  mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

                mBuilder.setContentTitle("New "+strContent[0].trim());
                mBuilder.setContentText("You've received new "+strContent[0].trim());
                mBuilder.setTicker("New "+strContent[0].trim()+" Alert!");
                mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notif);
                mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
                mBuilder.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorPrimary));
                mBuilder.setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
                mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
                mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[] {1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});         

                mBuilder.setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000);
             mBuilder.setNumber(++numMessages);

            NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

                String[] events = new String[strContent.length-1];
                for(int i=0; i<strContent.length-1; i++){
                    events[i] = new String(strContent[i+1].trim());
                }

                inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("New "+strContent[0].trim()+" received!");

                for (int i=0; i < events.length; i++) {
                    inboxStyle.addLine(events[i]);
                }

                mBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);

                /* Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app */
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, Splash_Activity.class);


                TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
                stackBuilder.addParentStack(Splash_Activity.class);

                /* Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack */
                stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
                PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
                NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                /* notificationID allows you to update the notification later on. */
                mNotificationManager.notify(9999, mBuilder.build());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Call method like this when u want notification

```
public void showNotification() {
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, ShowNotificationDetailActivity.class), 0);
        Resources r = getResources();
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.main)
                .setContentTitle("title")
                .setContentText("Welcome")
                .setContentIntent(pi)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
```

Create a class like this and give your class in the intent to go to activity

```
public class ShowNotificationDetailActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```